# Kotlinx Serialization Exception with Proguard and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to use kotlinx.serialization library with retrofit and coroutines. This combination is working fine unless I try to use proguard.

My proguard rules.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*, InnerClasses
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.SerializationKt
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.myapp.data.**$$serializer { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.data.* {
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.myapp.data.* {
     kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class com.myapp.data.features.featurename.entities.* { *; }
```

Here is the exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class e.f.a.d.c.b.a
    for method a.b
    at retrofit2.x.n(SourceFile:54)
    at retrofit2.j.e(SourceFile:126)
    at retrofit2.j.f(SourceFile:85)
    at retrofit2.u.b(SourceFile:39)
    at retrofit2.t.c(SourceFile:202)
    at retrofit2.t$a.invoke(SourceFile:160)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy13.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.api.n.c$e.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:49)
    at com.myapp.api.n.c$e.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.myapp.api.a.e(SourceFile:44)
    at com.myapp.api.n.c.b(SourceFile:48)
    at com.myapp.ui.splash.c$b.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:122)
    at kotlin.t.j.a.a.resumeWith(SourceFile:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.z0.run(SourceFile:56)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Can't locate argument-less serializer for class a. For generic classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.
    at kotlinx.serialization.h.a(SourceFile:21)
    at kotlinx.serialization.g.a(SourceFile:56)
    at e.e.c.b.a.a.b.d(SourceFile:23)
    at retrofit2.t.g(SourceFile:362)
    at retrofit2.t.i(SourceFile:345)
    at retrofit2.j.e(SourceFile:124)
    at retrofit2.j.f(SourceFile:85) 
    at retrofit2.u.b(SourceFile:39) 
    at retrofit2.t.c(SourceFile:202) 
    at retrofit2.t$a.invoke(SourceFile:160) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
    at $Proxy13.b(Unknown Source) 
    at com.myapp.api.n.c$e.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:49) 
    at com.myapp.api.n.c$e.invoke(Unknown Source:10) 
    at com.myapp.api.a.e(SourceFile:44) 
    at com.myapp.api.n.c.b(SourceFile:48) 
    at com.myapp.ui.splash.c$b.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:122) 
    at kotlin.t.j.a.a.resumeWith(SourceFile:33) 
    at kotlinx.coroutines.z0.run(SourceFile:56) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**kotlin version** *1.3.72*

**kotlinx.serializarion version** *0.20.0*

**retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter** *0.5.0*

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Do you have custom serializers? If yes you need to keep them too

Comment: no, I dont have any custom serializers.

Comment: Have you added [those rules](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro) for retrofit?

Comment: before I didnt but now I added the above rules and tried building again but getting the same error again. I also tried with invalidating the cache.